# Google Sheets | Return last Friday's date on Sat to Wed apart from Thu and Fri

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula, weekday

I'm a bit rubbish on Google Sheets formulas... would anyone be so kind to tell me how to achieve this ?

I'd like to have a cell that returns the last Friday's date on Sat to Wed, and instead the current date for Thursdays and Fridays.

Is it possible ?

e.g. this coming days:

Sat to Wed returns Friday 12th of March

Thu 18th returns Thu 18th

Fri 19th return Fri 19th

... and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but try this:

`=IF((WEEKDAY(TODAY())=5)+(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=6),TODAY(),TODAY()-VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),{7,1; 1,2; 2,3; 3,4; 4,5},2,FALSE))`

This formula is based on the us default numbers for weekdays, where Sunday = 1. If this formula produces unexpected results, your locale may be one where Monday = 1. In this case, you'll need to adjust as follows:

`=IF((WEEKDAY(TODAY())=4)+(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=5),TODAY(),TODAY()-VLOOKUP(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),{6,1; 7,2; 1,3; 2,4; 3,5},2,FALSE))`

Other things to keep in mind:

The `+` in (WEEKDAY(TODAY())=5)+(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=6) means `OR` (where `*` would mean `AND`).

The `VLOOKUP` is looking up the weekday of TODAY() within a simple virtual array, which is formed between the curly brackets and which instructs how many days to subtract from TODAY() given the current weekday in order to arrive at the previous Friday.